# how to change the location of components in the new gui builder codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am working on the GUI in my application right now and  am trying to position my components (labels, button's etc) but i cant change the location of the components. 
I can just change the layout to center or top but nothing else.
Can someone help me with positioning my components ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Component positioning is dictated by the layout manager of the container.  This may not seem as intuitive at the beginning but once you get a feel for the different layout managers that are available, it becomes easier.  It sounds like your container is currently using a BorderLayout which allows you to place components in north, south, east, west, and center.  The designer allows you to choose a different layout manager per container.  Nesting components with different layouts will allow you to get just about any positioning effect you desire.

A good place to start is the [Layout Managers section of the Developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/basics.html#basics-layout-managers-section).

Comment: yea but how i can for example to position label not in the left or center position but something in the middle. I mean how can i do a little padding without just choosing between left and center

Comment: Yes. This is a bit confusing right now.  Padding and Margin are considered part of the theme so they need to be edited in the theme, which is edited in the old Theme designer.  We are working on this currently and hope to make this easier with upcoming releases.  The GUI builder is handy for arranging the hierarchy.  For refining the styles and look (padding, borders, background images, etc..), you would use styles using either the theme designer or CSS (via the CSS library).

Comment: do you have assumption when the release will come out?